# find the limit of the sequence {$a_n$}?

Tags: real-analysis

if $a_1 \ge 0$ ,$a_2 \ge 0 $ and $a_{n+2} = \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}$. find the limit of the  sequence {$a_n$}

My answer : $ l = \sqrt{l\cdot l} $, $ l = 1 $

$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} {a_n} = 1 $

Is it correct ?

Comment: Wasn't $\sqrt{l\cdot l}=l$ for all $l\ge 0$ ?

Comment: No, clearly if either $a_1$ or $a_2$ equaled 0 then we have a limit of 0.  If $a_1=a_2$ then the limit is $a_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Yuchen showed, $x_n = C_1+\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^nC_2$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = C_1$.

We also have $x_1 = C_1+C_2 = \ln a_1$ and $x_2 = C_1-\dfrac{1}{2}C_2 = \ln a_2$.

Solving this system of equations gives $C_1 = \dfrac{1}{3}\ln a_1+\dfrac{2}{3}\ln a_2$.

So, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = e^{C_1} = \sqrt[3]{a_1a_2^2}$

Answer (score 3):

$$ \ln a_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}(\ln a_n +\ln a_{n+1}) $$

let $ x_n=\ln a_n $, we have

$$ x_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n+x_{n+1}) $$

Thus, $$ x_n=C_1+C_2(-\frac{1}{2})^n $$

where $ C_1, C_2 $ are constants depending on $ a_1, a_2 $. Hence, $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=C_1 $, $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=e^{C_1} $.

Comment: I think the limit should be given as a function of $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, apparently the question is missing some information for exact values of $ a_1, a_2 $.

Comment: Since the OP is looking for the limit as $n\to \infty$, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = C_1$. 

$x_1 = C_1+C_2 = \ln a_1$

$x_2 = C_1-\dfrac{1}{2}C_2 = \ln a_2$.

This gives $e^{C_1} = \sqrt[3]{a_1a_2^2}$.

$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \sqrt[3]{a_1a_2^2}$

Comment: How did you determine the explicit function of $x_n$?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe You should write an answer that gives $\sqrt[3]{a_1 a_2^2}$ as the result.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Right.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-recursive_sequence

Answer (score 2):

NO.

If you take $a_1 = a_2 = 1/2$ which gives $a_n = 1/2 $ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Hence, $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {a_n} = 1/2 \neq 1$

Comment: how can u directly claim that$ a_1 = a_2  =1/2 $ ..my question why  u didn't take $a_1 = a_2 = \frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Thats the point, @stupid.  We can make them whatever, right? There are no restrictions on what $a_0$ and $a_1$ can be, so there is no way to determine a precise numeric value for the limit.

Comment: I am not claiming $a_1 = a_2$. I have just given counter example to your claim that limit is 1.

Answer (score 2):

- As pointed out in the comment for any $l>0$, $l=\sqrt{l \cdot l}$ so this does not implies that $l=1$.
- You have to show that the limit exist before searching for the limit.
- A partial hint for this sequence is to define $v_n=\ln(a_n)$.

Then:
$$v_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2} \left(v_{n+1}+v_n \right)$$
and the roots of $X^2-\frac{1}{2} X-\frac{1}{2}$ are $1$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$.