# Recursive sequence limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> $$0<u_1<u_2 \text{ and } u_{n+2} =\sqrt{u_{n+1}. u_n}$$ Show that the limit of this sequence is ${(u_1.u_2^2)}^{1/3}$.

My attempt:
By computing individual terms I see that every term can be written in terms of $u_1$and $u_2$. Also this sequence is monotonic increasing and it also has an upper bound by the AM GM inequality. But it doesnot seem to get me anywhere. Please help.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2763580/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**
Let $\left(v_n\right)$ be the sequence defined by $v_n=u_{n}u_{n+1}^2$ then
$$
v_{n+1}=u_{n+1}u_{n+2}^2=u_{n+1}\times\left(u_{n+1}u_n\right)=u_nu_{n+1}^2=v_n
$$
As $v_{n+1}=v_n$ for all $n$, the sequence $\left(u_nu_{n+1}^2\right)$ is constant, so for all $n$, $v_n=v_1$ which means
$$
u_nu_{n+1}^2=u_1u_2^2
$$

If you succeed in showing that the sequence $\left(u_n\right)$ converges, you have your limit :
if $u_n \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}\ell$ then you have
$$
\ell\times \ell^2=u_1u_{2}^2 \Rightarrow \ell=\left(u_1u_2^2\right)^{1/3}
$$

Comment: I am sorry but I didn’t get how is that a constant sequence. Also, we need a cube root in our limit.

Comment: I edited my answer so you can better understand how i proceeded